Troubleshooting Flet Build Errors for Windows and Android Compilation
I wonder if anyone can help me with a problem regarding Flet? The problem occurs when trying to compile my software for any platform. Well, I formatted my pc, I’m with the latest version of Windows 10 pro. All dependencies properly installed and configured:
–- version
Python -–version = Python 3.12.4 
Flutter -– version = Flutter 3.22.2 channel stable
Flet -– version = 0.22.1 

Flutter Doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.4474], locale pt-BR)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.10.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.90.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!

When I execute the command flet run main.py the app enter image description here, but when using the command flet build windows main.py or flet build apk main.py I receive the enter image description here:
flet build windows main.py Path to Flet app does not exist or is not a directory: C:\Users\mnd\OneDrive\Documentos\projects\python\clc\main.py
I recently started using Flet and wanted to compile my project for windows and android, but I’m getting errors. I tried with several projects and in different folders on the computer and even external hard drive. But the problem doesn’t seem to be related to any of this.
